# Xamarin Forms NavigationPage small part of previous page visible when navigating on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

I'm facing a very awkward trouble with my XF NavigationPage on iOS, and can't find anything about it on google. When I navigate from one page to another using Navigation.PushAsync there is 1pt line of previous page on the left of the screen visible untill replace that loading page's content from codebehind, you can see it here: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmdaD.jpg) (I actually have an image im my XAML and it's replaced with content that is loaded from server). If I disable animations with false param on PushAsync this dosen't happen.

Is there any way to preserve animations and get rid of this? Any suggestions appreciated, thank's in advance.

Comment: Xf Version details?

Comment: Thank you very much G.hakim, for some reason update all did not update my xamarin.forms package. Explicit update did the trick (as far as i can see on the simulator). If you post an answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to the Latest version of `Xamarin Forms`, as I remember facing this bug on some previous version of XF probably 3.5 something but when i updated to the latest it started working

Good luck

Revert in case of queries

Comment: I was using 3.5.0.xxxxxx (don't remeber exactly) but not the latest one